# How to convert two json properties that have same name into properties in same class

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a json object:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": "xxx"
    },
    "session": {
        "id": "xxx"
    }
}
```

now I need to convert json into a class,

my default answer is to write properties as UserID,sessionID

but I wish something like User.ID & session.ID(which is not possible) from readability point of view.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? Just write a User class and a Session class...

Comment: You only need an object with two properties (`user` and `session`). Those properties are objects with properties called `id` but that's no problem.

Comment: I'll just leave this right here:  http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Kenneth K, thanks,it works but I need to map my json , I am going with Newtonsoft.json.  [JsonPropertyName("User/Id")]

Answer (score 1):

Make a base class:

```
public class BaseId //Come up with a better name
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then inherit it from these classes:

```
public class User : BaseId 
{
    //Other stuff if you want
}

public class Session : BaseId 
{
    //Other stuff if you want
}
```

However you should only do this if User and Session have unique differences from one another (but obviously share the ID property).

If you just want two different variables, then parse them into two different instances of the BaseId class named `user` and `session` (obviously no need for the concrete classes this way)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JsonProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) class of `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserId")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SessionId")]
    public int ID1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this actually compile? Seems like you would have a duplicate identifier error

Comment: Hi Rahul, actuall I have something different that what you said, I have a JsonProperty  with name 'user' and the 'user' property had inner JsonProperty with name 'ID' which has some value . now I have another JsonProperty at the level of 'user' with name 'session' and this had an inner JsonProperty with name 'ID'

Comment: thanks for suggesting Newtonsoft.json.  " [JsonPropertyName("User/Id")]  " will this work mapping "User" properties inner property "ID" value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question entirely. If I were to do this, it would look like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("user")]
    public User UserIdentity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("session")]
    public Session CurrentSession { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Session
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arman, I think what you said might not work,  beacuse user has some other JsonProperties also and same with sessions

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can add additional properties to session or user, it's not limited to just id. You can chain them up anyway you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Session
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class MyJson 
{
    [JsonProperty("user")]
    private User user { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("session")]
    private Session session { get; set; }     
    public string UserID { get { return user.id; }  } 
    public string SessionID { get { return session.id; } }
}
```

You Can Write the Model of This type, You can Get the Data As You Request Type of UserID and SessionID.

In Below Sample Code For Testting

```
 var teststring = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>("{\"user\": {\"id\": \"xxx\"},\"session\": {\"id\": \"xxx\"}");
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJson>(teststring.ToString());
 var session = data.SessionID;
 var userId = data.UserID;
```

I Was Checked Properly. It Working fine.